# Initialising via JavaScript after loading ember route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a route in ember, say 'about'. When I click on the link-to handler to load the route, I need to initialise a clockpicker via JavaScript like

```
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
```

Now, where do I do this as I need to wait for the route to load the templates for this to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run that in the view's [didInsertElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) hook.

In your AboutView:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
}
```